# Create a empty array/list of a data class and assign a type to it

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create an empty array/list of a  data class and assign a type to it
I prefer to assign Types so that I can find errors better, I'm pretty new to python and not sure how to handle issues of not giving the correct type for data, and having it typed lets the IDE better help me out.

Anyway, this code works :

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,sample,text):
        self.sample = sample
        self.text = text
        
arr = []#note I have to give it some sort of empty array, because I'm adding the data needed later in a "for" loop

arr.append(myClass("hello1","world2"))
arr.append(myClass("hello1","world2"))

for item in arr:
    print(item.sample + " " + item.text)
```

Here is what is not working my attempt to force a Type onto a Variable

I have tried this but it gives a exception

```
arr2: list[myClass] = None
arr2.append(myClass("hello3","world3"))
arr2.append(myClass("hello4","world4"))
for item in arr2:
    print(item.sample + " " + item.text)
#'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have tried this too but it gives a exception

```
arr3: list[myClass] = myClass(None,None)
arr3.append(myClass())
arr3.append(myClass("hello5","world5"))
arr3.append(myClass("hello6","world6"))
for item in arr3:
    print(arr3[item].sample + " " + arr3[item].text)
#'myClass' object has no attribute 'append'
```

So again my goal is to give the "arr" a type of "myClass" but I want an array of that class's data

Comment: I'm a bit lost in this question, I do not undertand what you are trying to do. But the originof your errors is that **arr** in example1 is list, thus you can append things to it (no error). In example 2  **arr2** is None, and example3  **arr3** is an instance of myClass in any of these two case the object have append method and that is why you get the error. You can assign a type list ```arr: list[myClass] = []```, that should work

Comment: that's it, Thanks. I'm new to python (i use C# for most things) and don't understand the syntax all too well of it yet. I thought that the list in list[myClass] already signified an array. basically, I'm treating my class as a data table to store my info, but I want to enforce more strict typing of variables becue I cannot keep track of all the cooky variable names, the IDE must help me with that. Anyway now I just have to go and figure out how to strict type more things... hehehe

Comment: Good to hear that this solve your problem.